# POSTING data to server and reading it on server end

Tags: android

### I have followed the process of encoding the data in android Using Base64

**client** :: android

1. The data i have encoded comprised of string and image
2. Now on decoding on server should i decode the data into binary to
   store it all together?
3. Or Should i need to decode a string to a particular format and image
   to particular format- If so what are those formats ?

**My endgoal**::

- store image as Jpeg in server disc
- data in database

I am confused with Base64format, Jpgformat etc

Any guidance on this

### {EDIT}

**For image**

it is like this::

- I need to be able to see the image when i give its location URL in
  server....
- with this regard i need to store it in server .....
- How should i process the posted Base64 encoded image in server ?

**for string it is like this**::

- there is no need of decoding even if its Base64 encoded to store it in database ?

**Note**:: I never use Decoding on client when GET is used to get the data which are uploaded to server as Base64 encoded !

Answer (score 1):

please read follwing link .....how to store image in servier

http://reecon.wordpress.com/2010/04/25/uploading-files-to-http-server-using-post-android-sdk/

Comment: So if i encode data into Base64 format and send it there is no need for me to decode it before saving it in server ?

Comment: you have to pass file path it will convert bytestream .. server side you have to store file into folder(from post method you will get filepath)... after server file path you have to store in mysql database

Comment: Okie so ..... thats exactly where i am confused ..... while storing the file into folder on server .... is there a need for me to do some kind of decoding before ? ..... Also for string as i store directly the param value should i need to decode it on server before saving it in database ?

Answer (score 1):

It will Depends on your server side.. That how do you want to Store the Image??? If you want to save your image as a filepath or only as a image path then after it will be converted to byteStream.

If you want to save your image as byte array then you can also do that...after that you don't need to decoding..... And after that you can save your image to your Database.....

**For String:**

When you are posting the string then no need for decoding....And it is used when you need to remove some special characters from your String...

Like:

```
String name = URLDecoder.decode("yourString","UTF-8");
```

after that you can save your String in your  Database.....

Comment: @ Piyush Gupta ...... Thanks .... i got some idea ... i added more info to question .... can you add more details based on that ? :)

Comment: @smriti3 Yeah..If i familiar with it then sure.

Comment: Thanks, i am not asking the code on server end .... i just need to understand the concept !